# Concat the string with linq to entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5, dynamic-linq

I'm using the [`Dynamic Linq`](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) with `Linq to Entities`

So, I tested the normal `List<Person>` with this code and everything's work:

```
 List<Person> per = new List<Person>();
 per.Add(new Person { IdNo = "1", LastName = "test", MiddleName = "go", FirstName = "let" });
 per.Add(new Person { IdNo = "2", LastName = "hope", MiddleName = "is", FirstName = "way" });
 per.Add(new Person { IdNo = "3", LastName = "must", MiddleName = "be", FirstName = "human" });
 per.Add(new Person { IdNo = "4", LastName = "thing", MiddleName = "anywhere", FirstName = "can" });
 per.Add(new Person { IdNo = "5", LastName = "bird", MiddleName = "fly", FirstName = "away" });

 List<object> paramObjects = new List<object>();
 List<string> fields = new List<string>();
 fields.Add("IdNo == @0");
 paramObjects.Add("1");

 fields.Add("or (LastName + \", \" + MiddleName + \" \" + FirstName).Contains(@1)");
 paramObjects.Add("m");

 var where = string.Join(" ", fields.ToArray());
 var toParam = paramObjects.ToArray();

 var query = per.AsQueryable().Where(where, toParam).ToList();
```

and when I'm in `Linq To Entities` approach.

```
using(var con = new DbContext())
{
   var query = con.Person.Where(where, toParam).ToList();
}
```

I got this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   Concat(System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot
>   be translated into a store expression.

My question is:

How to `Concat` the string using the `Linq To Entities` base in my example using the *Dynamic Linq*? Anyone can help me?

Comment: Have you tried `ToString()`?

Comment: Did you mean like `(LastName + \", \" + MiddleName + \" \" + FirstName).ToString().Contains(@1)` this will be the error → `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()'`

Comment: No, I mean `"or (LastName.ToString() + \", \" + LastName.ToString() + \" \" + LastName.ToString()).Contains(@1)"`

Comment: yes. i tested.. still error exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Option 1:

  Change the line...

  ```
  fields.Add("or (LastName + \", \" + MiddleName + \" \" + FirstName).Contains(@1)");
  ```

  ...to

  ```
  fields.Add("or string.Concat(LastName, \", \", MiddleName, \" \", FirstName).Contains(@1)");
  ```
- Option 2:

  Open the `Dynamic.cs` file of the Dynamic LINQ library, search for `"GenerateStringConcat"` in that file. You should find this method:

  ```
  Expression GenerateStringConcat(Expression left, Expression right) {
      return Expression.Call(
          null,
          typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat",
              new[] { typeof(object), typeof(object) }),
          new[] { left, right });
  }
  ```

  Change the `object` parameter types to `string`, that is:

  ```
  Expression GenerateStringConcat(Expression left, Expression right) {
      return Expression.Call(
          null,
          typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat",
              new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) }),
          new[] { left, right });
  }
  ```

Keep in mind that Dynamic LINQ is not a special "LINQ-to-Entities library", but a general library for `IQueryable`. There might be Queryable providers that support `string.Concat(object, object)` with the general `object` parameter, but LINQ-to-Entities does not. It only supports the `string` parameter versions of `string.Concat`. Looking through the Dynamic LINQ file when `GenerateStringConcat` is actually called (only once) I believe the change above is safe as long as you only want to use the library with LINQ-to-Entities/Entity Framework.

**Edit**

Option 1 does not work because `Concat` gets more than *four*  string parameters in the example. It only works up to four parameters because `string.Concat` has an overload with four explicit `string` parameters. It doesn't seem to be possible to use the overload with the array parameter `params string[]` in Dynamic LINQ.

Comment: thank you sir, but unfortunately the _option 1: is not working_ the error is `No applicable method 'Concat' exists in type 'String'`, I will try the option 2.

Comment: just applied the _option 2._ the error still `No applicable method 'Concat' exists in type 'String'`

Comment: @spajce: To your first comment: I am sorry, I tested only with three parameters, not with five, as in your example. Option 1 doesn't work with five parameters (see Edit to my answer). To your comment 2: When you use option 2, use your original query string with the `+` concatenation, not the explicit "string.Concat(...)" in the query string.

Comment: wow.. its working! `the option 2` wow thank you very much! +2  and thanks for the explanation also .. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but with NHibernate, my solution was to modify  GenerateStringConcat Method

I change this:

```
static Expression GenerateStringConcat(Expression left, Expression right)
    {   
        return Expression.Call(
            null,
            typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new[] { typeof(object), typeof(object) }),
            new[] { left, right });
    }
```

For this:

```
static Expression GenerateStringConcat(Expression left, Expression right)
    {            
        return Expression.Add(
            left,
            right,
            typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new[] { typeof(object), typeof(object) })
        );
    }
```

He has worked quite well :)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 var where = string.Join(" ", fields.ToArray());
```

to

```
string where = string.Empty;
foreach(var f in fields)
{
    where += f + " "; 
}

where = where.Trim();
```

Comment: I have no problem about the `string.Join` even if we will not use that, the error is still occurred.